# Access token cleared after relaunching the application Google Signin iOS

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have implemented Google Sign in in my app, below in my Sign in code,

```
- (IBAction)googleSignIn:(id)sender {
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance]signIn];
}
```

And implemented delegate as follows,

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    _socialLoginPlatform = @"Google";
    if (user != nil) {
        NSDictionary *params = @{ @"UserName": user.profile.email,
                                  @"Email":user.profile.email,
                                  @"FullName": user.profile.name,
                                  @"Provider":@"Google",
                                  @"ExternalAccessToken":user.authentication.accessToken,
                                  @"Platform": @"IOS"
                                  };
        if (user.profile.hasImage) {
            kAppDelegate.profilePicture =  [[user.profile imageURLWithDimension:80]absoluteString];
        }
        [self authorizeExternalAccessTokenWithParameters:params];
    }

}
```

This is working fine as long as app is in foreground but when quit and relaunched the access token is cleared, when I do,

```
 GIDGoogleUser *user = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance]currentUser];
 NSString *token = user.authentication.accessToken;
```

The token is null, Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Store your access token in NSuserdefault so its not clear when you quite your app.

Answer (score 0):

**[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] is a shared instance**. So token is stored in the memory. It will be cleared, once your app gets killed by the user or OS.

You have to store that token in a place, where it can be retrieved even after the app has been removed from memory once you get the token. Two ways it is possible 1.User defaults 2. key chain which is far secure.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:token forKey:@"GoogleSigninToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Get the existing token from NSUserDefault in AppDelegate

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"GoogleSigninToken"];
      if (token == nil) {
        // Then user has not signed in.
      }

    }
```